# Firebase Dynamic link handling always gives error

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-dynamic-links

Thank you in advanced for giving your valuable time for reading this.

I have tried to implement dynamic link through firebase sdk.
Have gone through provided documents for implementing this by firebase. 

 Issue I face is when I share dynamic link through application generated using below code

```
    guard let link = URL(string: "\(Constant.dynamicLinkBaseUrl)\(urlPathComponent)/\(encShareDetail ?? "")") else { return }
    let dynamicLinksDomainURIPrefix = Constant.DomainURIPrefix
    let linkBuilder = DynamicLinkComponents(link: link, domainURIPrefix: dynamicLinksDomainURIPrefix)
    linkBuilder?.iOSParameters = DynamicLinkIOSParameters(bundleID: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier ?? Constant.AppBundleID)
    
    linkBuilder?.navigationInfoParameters?.isForcedRedirectEnabled = true
    linkBuilder?.iOSParameters?.fallbackURL = URL(string:Constant.AppStoreFallbackUrl)
    linkBuilder?.androidParameters = DynamicLinkAndroidParameters(packageName: Constant.AndroidPackageName)
    linkBuilder?.androidParameters?.fallbackURL = URL(string: Constant.AndroidFallbackUrl)
    linkBuilder?.shorten() { url, warnings, error in
      print("URL :: \(String(describing: url?.absoluteString))\nWarnings :: \(String(describing: warnings?.debugDescription))\nError :: \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
      guard let url = url, error == nil else { return }
      print("The short URL is: \(url)")
      tabBarControllerObj?.presentDefaultShare(videoURL: url.absoluteString)
    }
```

On taping the generated link in device, my application is launched and it am able to get the generated dynamic link in

```
scene(_ scene: UIScene, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity)
```

method, I'm able to get the link with the below code

```
guard userActivity.activityType == NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb,
          let url = userActivity.webpageURL,
          let host = url.host else {
      return
    }
    print("URL :: \(url.absoluteString)\nHost :: \(host.debugDescription)")
```

but not able to get the deep link I have created as when I called the method

```
DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().handleUniversalLink(url)
```

It returns with error as **"The operation couldn’t be completed. Universal link URL could not be parsed by Dynamic Links."**

Don't found any solution related to this as the same Dynamic link is working fine for Android app.

Please help me as I'm stuck with it for around 4 days.[image: Flow Diagram for dynamic link seems fine too.]

Comment: Hey, where you able to find any solution for this particular issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by adding all my url prefixes to info.plist.

```
<key>FirebaseDynamicLinksCustomDomains</key>
        <array>
          <string>https://<custom domain>/login</string>
          <string>https://<custom domain>/</string>
        </array>
```

More details at https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/custom-domains#console